# Cannot use bootstrap.js but can use bootstrap.css with zend framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a web application using Zend framework with Bootstrap. I placed the bootstrap folder with the js and css subfolders within a 'library' folder inside the 'public' folder of my project like so:

project>public>library>bootstrap>css and js.

There is a index.php in this folder that calls index.phtml under project>application>views>scripts>index folder which I edited by including the following lines inside the 'head' tag

```
<link href='library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'  type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css'>
```

This works fine.

Now, I also included the following lines just before the /body tag

```
<script src="library/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="library/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Here, I am unable to use any of the javascript methods, eg. the dropdown effect does not work at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which error are you getting, have you check developer console in chrome or firefox?

Comment: the dropdown menu does not work at all. And I copy pasted this html file to another document and the dropdown works fine. im not sure how to debug it using developer console

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome then in the console tab the errors will be shown in red. It can give you a few pointers about the error.

Comment: Here are the errors:
1.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://hardware.localhost/library/bootstrap/js/jquery.js


2.Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery bootstrap.js:9


3.event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.


4.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It's loading the bootstrap.js the problem is that cannot reach the jquery file, that's why you get that 403, it's not loading at all, maybe is a permission issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error it show in the Developer Console in Chrome:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) hardware.localhost/library/bootstrap/js/jquery.js

and

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery bootstrap.js

You can see bootstrap it's loading fine but jquery is not. The **403 error** points to a permission error while you are trying to access jquery.js. Check the correct file location and permissions and it should work.